# How to find top n% of records in a column of a dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset showing the exchange rate of the Australian Dollar versus the US dollar once a day over a period of about 20 years.  I have the data in a data frame, with the first column being the date, and the second column being the exchange rate.   Here's a sample from the data:

```
>data
             V1     V2
1    12/12/1983 0.9175
2    13/12/1983 0.9010
3    14/12/1983 0.9000
4    15/12/1983 0.8978
5    16/12/1983 0.8928
6    19/12/1983 0.8770
7    20/12/1983 0.8795
8    21/12/1983 0.8905
9    22/12/1983 0.9005
10   23/12/1983 0.9005
```

How would I go about displaying the top n% of these records?  E.g. say I want to see the days and exchange rates for those days where the exchange rate falls in the top 5% of all exchange rates in the dataset?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For the top 5%:

```
n <- 5
data[data$V2 > quantile(data$V2,prob=1-n/100),]
```

Comment: Or to save a little typing: `subset(data, V2 > quantile(V2, prob = 1 - n/100))`

Comment: Or using `data.table`:  `setDT(data)[V2 > quantile(V2, probs = 1 - n/100)]`

Answer (score 9):

For the top 5% also:

```
head(data[order(data$V2,decreasing=T),],.05*nrow(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be use for `sqldf` if the data is sorted based on the `V1` value:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT * FROM df
       ORDER BY V1
       LIMIT (SELECT 0.05 * COUNT(*) FROM df)
      ')
```

You can change the rate form `0.05` (`5%`) to any required rate.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution could look like this:

```
obs <- nrow(data) 
data %>% filter(row_number() < obs * 0.05)
```

This only works if the data is sorted, but your question and example data implies this. If the data is unsorted, you will need to `arrange` it by the variable you're interested in:

`data <- data %>% arrange(desc(V2))`